# Enable alertdialog "ok" button after x seconds

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog that displays information when the app boots for the first time. Since users these days, always click "ok" without reading the text. I would like to disable the OK button for the first 5 seconds (preferably with countdown inside). How can this be accomplished?

My code (not very necessary):

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Very usefull info here!")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(which).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             // the rest of your stuff
        }
        })
        .show();
```

I hope this is helpful to other users to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// Create a handler
Handler handler = new Handler();

// Build the dialog
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("Very usefull info here!")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // the rest of your stuff
    }
})
.create();

dialog.show();

// Access the button and set it to invisible
final Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

// Post the task to set it visible in 5000ms         
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    }}, 5000);
```

This will enable the button after 5 seconds. This does look a bit messy, but it works. I welcome anyone who has a cleaner version!

Answer (score 0):

A Kotlin implementation with countdown. The counter is not pretty but it's fine for this.

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n") // counter, nothing to translate
private fun setApproveDialog() {

    val label = getString(R.string.ok)
    
    val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.approve_task).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.approve_task_warning))
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("$label - 3") { dialogInterface, _ ->
            setApprove()
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
        }
        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.back)) { dialogInterface, _ ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
        }
        .create()

    alert.show()

    val button = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

    button.isEnabled = false

    with(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
        postDelayed({ if (alert.isShowing) button.text = "$label - 2" }, 1000)
        postDelayed({ if (alert.isShowing) button.text = "$label - 1" }, 2000)
        postDelayed({
            if (alert.isShowing) {
                button.text = label
                button.isEnabled = true
            }
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```